# Problem occurred while web crawling instagram

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, web-crawler, executable-path

```
def insta_searching(word):
    url = "https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/" + str(word)
    return url
def select_first(driver):
    first = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div._9AhH0")[0] # Updated selector for the first post
    first.click()
    time.sleep(3)
def get_content(driver):
    html = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    
    try:
        content = soup.select('div.C4VMK > span')[0].text # Updated selector for post content
    except:
        content = ''
    tags = re.findall(r'#[^\s#,\\]+', content)
    date = soup.select('time.FH9sR.Nzb55')[0]['datetime'][:10] # Updated selector for post date
    
    try:
        place = soup.select('div.M30cS')[0].text # Updated selector for post location
    except:
        place = ''
    data = [content, date, place, tags]
    return data
def move_next(driver):
    right = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a._65Bje.coreSpriteRightPaginationArrow") # Updated selector for right arrow
    right.click()
    time.sleep(3)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\Smart\Desktop\chromedriver-win64\chromedriver.exe')

driver.get('https://www.instagram.com') # Fixed line
time.sleep(3)
```

Error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_11388\2581174010.py in <module>
----> 1 driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\Smart\Desktop\chromedriver-win64\chromedriver.exe')
      2 
      3 driver.get('https://www.instagram.com') # Fixed line
      4 time.sleep(3)

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'executable_path'
```

This part keeps returns error and I don't know how to fix this.
I thought this might be because the version of chrome and `chromedriver` is different so I tried to download the same version. But the version for chrome is `116.0.5845.97` and there aren't the same version of `chromedriver` available for me to download. It would be wonderful if you can tell me a way to fix this error. please send help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With selenium `v4.10.0`, you need to pass `executable_path` in `Service` class. Refer below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service(executable_path='./chromedriver.exe')
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
```

Having said that, if you do not want to set the `chromedriver.exe` path manually, then you can simplify the code as below:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.instagram.com')
```

Selenium's new tool `Selenium Manager` will do the download and management of `driver.exe` for you.

References:

- [executable_path deprecated](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/9f5801c82fb3be3d5850707c46c3f8176e3ccd8e)
- [Introducing Selenium Manager](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/introducing-selenium-manager/)